# Process.Responding detects process exit, while process runs

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have trouble with checking if a process is still running.
I created a small program that should keep 2 programs up and running.
For this example I use Notepad and windows calculator.
The Code below will launch both applications, but its failing on checking their running state by their process.checkalive propert also hasexited fails.

Notice that the sample program uses a class Apprunner to handle multiple applications. After launching both applications it crashes with:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   'Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.'

Despite that both programs Notepad.exe and Calc.exe are running.

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace watchdog 
{
class AppRunner
{
  public Process Program;

  public AppRunner(ProcessStartInfo processrunner)
  {
    this.Program = new Process();
        this.Program.StartInfo = processrunner;
    StartExecute();
  }
  public void StartExecute()
  {
    this.Program.Start();
  }
  public bool checkAlive()
  {
    this.Program.Refresh();
    return (bool)this.Program.Responding; 
    //fails
    // also failing as true   => return this.Program.HasExited; 
    //(its not true app still runs)
  }
  public void KeepEmRunning()
  {
    if (!checkAlive())
    {
        StartExecute();
    }
  }
}

//-----------main prog -  - - - - 
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     List<AppRunner> programs = new List<AppRunner>();

     ProcessStartInfo prog = new ProcessStartInfo();
     ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\Notepad.exe";


      programs.Add(new AppRunner(startInfo));
      startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\Calc.exe";
      programs.Add(new AppRunner(startInfo));

      string s;
      do
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);// wait for start.
            Console.WriteLine("Notepad" + programs[0].checkAlive());
            Console.WriteLine("Calc" + programs[1].checkAlive());
            Console.WriteLine("press X for exit other key for update");
            s = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        } while (s != "X");
    }
   }
 }
```

Code running on Windows 10, and vs2017 its a .net 4.6 console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`Process.Responding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an exception if the process has already exited. I guess `Responding`'s purpose is to check if the process is dead-locked or still working, but doesn't work if the process is gone already.
2. `Calc.exe` indeed immediatly returns, after starting `Calculator.exe` (see TaskManager). So the result you observe is correct: the process you started for `calc.exe` has already exited, although you still see a calculator window.

Comment: Though the processes notepad and calculator are still running

Comment: @user3800527 did you verfiy via TaskManager that there is a `notepad.exe` and a `calc.exe` process running? afaik, `notepad.exe` starts the default editor (which maybe notepad, but not necessarily), and on my win10, `calc.exe` starts `Calculator.exe` and _terminates_. Please verify via TaskManager and not only by open windows.

Comment: Yes before i run above application i kill, any notepad.exe, and calc.exe trough taskmanager, then when i run the program both applications popup (they are running) but the program checkResponding fails.

Comment: @user3800527 by "popup" you mean these processes (`notepad.exe` _and_ `calc.exe`) appear in the TaskManager? Or are we still talking about the calculator window popping up (again: this is - at least on my machine - `calculator.exe`, not `calc.exe`). And yes, if `calc.exe` exited (which it does), `Responding` will throw, just like the documentation I linked states.

Comment: @user3800527 as a debugging hint: try to narrow the problem by investigating only one process. I'm sure with `notepad` alone everything works fine (excpet for the throwing `Responding` when `notepad` exited), and it's only `calc.exe` which causes the problem (because it terminates immediatly after starting `calculator.exe`).

Comment: Does calculator stop working at your PC ?, here it keeps running.
As for detection i also tried Program.HasExited in checkAlive(), but width the same behaviour.

Comment: @user3800527 can you please give an _exact_ answer? "calculator running" is not exact: does the `calc.exe` process still run? or is it a `calculator.exe` process started by `calc.exe`? The fact that you see a calculator is **not** an answer to that question. Since the `Process` class has been tested by million of developers over decades, I'm sure it's correct in determining if the process is running or not. So as long as you don't tell me otherwise, I'm sure the calculator window you **see** is the newly started **calculator.exe** process, not your `calc.exe` process.

Comment: only calc.exe runs  ( i dont have calculator.exe ), its the line startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\Calc.exe";  that startups a calculator which is calc.exe

Comment: @user3800527 I need to be sure, did you see calc.exe in your TaskManager? I start the process via "...\calc.exe", too, but this process immediatly terminates and starts "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1705.1301.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\calculator.exe". Seems `calc.exe` is a proxy to start the (user-defined) default calculator app. Even if this default app is the same `calc.exe`, it may be (re-)started as new process. The process you started _did_ terminate, so `HasExited` returns true for you. The question actually is: how to recognize child processes? don't know this

Comment: OMG... that wasnt a good test scenario, i didnt knew it was spawning another calculator. 
2nd time now with Charmap it works well.